# unable to login in Error: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: no such file or directory

Tags: boot, mount, initramfs

I was editing my disk space and I think I did something wrong. Now I can't login to my ubuntu. It was working well before. It is now stuck at initramfs.

I have 2 hard disk 2. Dual boot. One windows and One of linux.

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I ran this via a terminal then restarted my server

```
ln -sf /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/lvm2 /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternate solution is to go to recovery console, login to root shell, and resume. You can now login.